# How to prepare photo data for training model to recognize bowling ball name, brand and manufacturer from photo of bowling ball?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, object-recognition

I am asked to do this. The client can only prepare a only one photo for each ball from the product page of bowling manufacturer. 
However, I need huge amount of image data for each ball.

Here is what I am thinking. To fake thousands pieces of photo data, turn the ball into 3D model and take thousands of photo of that ball from different perspective in software like Maya or 3DS Max.

I am not sure if this would work for detecting balls in reality since the source of data is not real.

Would my approach of preparation of image data from virtual environment work for training model for detecting objects in reality?

BTW, I do not have specialty in data science. I just have very fundamental concepts of ML. What algorithm would you suggest for my case?

Thanks!